# Can't run clj file cause "couldn't locate" in cljs+clj project

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, leiningen

I have 2 project: my backend on Clojure and frontend on ClojureScript.
I decided to merge them. So i copied files from both projects, runed `lein deps` and try to start my backend. So i got this error

```
Couldn't locate web.clj on classpath
```

In my project source-paths:

```
["src/clj" "src/cljs"]
```

And `main ^:skip-aot clj.web`
My frontend is working properly. 
My folder structure:

```
src
  clj
    web.clj
  cljs
    *some cljs files*
```

So how can i setup my `source-paths` setting to run my backend?

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is that you seem to have no subfolders under src/clj… this would be necessary in order to have your Clojure namespaces consist of at least two parts (as they should). I'd try to move your web.clj to /src/clj/projectname/web.clj and change the ns declaration to `(ns projectname.web…)`. Then change the entry point (e.g. main fn) in your project.clj accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The namespace you want to start is not `clj.web` but `web` so your `project.clj` file should have:

```
main ^:skip-aot web
```

And your `web.clj` file should being with:

```
(ns web)
```

If you use subfolders in the future, the namespaces will be mapped with the [following rules](https://clojure.org/reference/libs#_example_lib):

> `(ns com.my-company.clojure.examples.my-utils)`
>
> The `ns` form names the lib’s namespace and declares its dependencies. Based on its name, this lib is typically defined in a source file at the classpath-relative path: com/my_company/clojure/examples/my_utils.clj (note the translations from period to slash and hyphen to underscore).